# Аппаратное ускорение в Awesomium.NET

Tags: c#, awesomium

Использую Awesomium.NET.

В браузерных онлайн играх не работает аппаратное ускорение и мип-маппинг.
То же самое происходит, когда я открываю игру в Shockwave Flash Object.
При нажатии ПКМ->Параметры, стоит галочка на "аппаратное ускорение".

Что делать, как фиксить?

Данный код не помог:

```
webControl1.ViewType = WebViewType.Window;
WebPreferences wp = new WebPreferences();
wp.EnableGPUAcceleration = true;
wp.WebGL = true;
WebSession ws = WebCore.CreateWebSession(wp);
webControl1.WebSession = ws;
```

Comment: Если та же проблема у Flash, может, что-то не так с машиной? Воспроизводится ли проблема на других компьютерах?

Comment: В браузере Chrome все работает хорошо.

Comment: @VladD, UPD в вопросе.

Comment: Хм. Согласно [документации](http://wiki.awesomium.net/wpf/webcontrol.html) вы вроде всё сделали правильно. Может, стоит написать в тех. поддержку?

Comment: @VladD, да, пожалуй, а можно ссылочку?

Comment: На их техоподдержку? Я не знаю, но неужели на оф. сайте проекта нету?

Comment: Вот, кстати: http://www.awesomium.com/support

Comment: Такая же проблема и у меня. Ты ее как-нибудь решил?

Comment: @АндрейДиневич Нет, я забил на это все. Никак не решил. Возможно движок такой..